# Arrange given numbers in ascending order

Tags: c, arrays

I've just started learning C, and today I was given a question in which one of the parts was to accept the array of numbers from user and arrange them in ascending order. The array size was also to be specified by user.
I used the following code for this purpose->

```
   for (i = 0; i <= y - 1; ++i) {
        for (ii = i + 1; ii <= y - 1; ++ii) {
            if (x[i] > x[ii]) {
                temp = x[i];
                x[i] = x[ii];
                x[ii] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    int k;
    printf("\nNumbers arranged in ascending order:\n");
    for (k = 0; k < y; ++k) {
        printf("%d\n", x[i]);
    }
```

Here, variable y is the size of array, x is name of array variable (So the variable defining goes like this-> `int x[y];`
But the problem is, it just prints out the final value of array. To elaborate problem:
Suppose I entered 3 as my array size. Then program asks me for 3 numbers which I chose 34,45,22.
Now after this whole code is executed, it displays x[3] (now x[3] doesn't even exist! Since x[2] is final value in array. So it gives me memory location of variable.)
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Since _variable y is the size of array_: `int x[y]`, your sorting loops each go one value too large. A C array of size _y_ is indexable between `0` and `y-1`. Just change the `<=` to `<` and you'll have them right.

Comment: Cool piece of code if you are just a few days into C! Some remarks: never use y for integers, use i, j, k. (Everybody else does it like that, comes form FORTRAN, dont ask). use `for (i = 0; i < y; i++)` for similar reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change

```
 printf("%d\n", x[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", x[k]);
```

in the printing loop as you're using `k` as the loop counter variable.

Comment: Aah thanks, such a little mistake. Dont know why I didnt notice it lol, I must have read the upper loops a thousand times to check my logic, but final loop.... thanks a lot :D Once the time break of 10mins passes, i'll choose it as the answer (SO limits)

Answer (score 0):

In your last for loop, you are doing

```
 printf("\nNumbers arranged in ascending order:\n");
for (k = 0; k < y; ++k) {
    printf("%d\n", x[i]);
}
```

but you print `x[i]`, but do not increment `i`. Remember, `i` and `k` are just array variables, not the actual VALUES in the array. Just change the `printf` to `printf("%d\n", x[k]);` and it should work fine.